# Eliminate unnecessary Bower files in production

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, requirejs, bower

I have a Django app running on Heroku that uses Bower to manage front-end dependencies.  These dependencies, along with my application, are optimized with RequireJS and served up using Amazon S3.  Is there an easy way for me to know what files in my bower_components directory can be safely deleted from my static file server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to use [django-pipeline](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to process front-end assets.  django-pipeline will:

> ...help you by excluding much of the extra content that Bower includes
>   with its components, such as READMEs, tests and examples, while still
>   including images, fonts, CSS fragments etc.

(from [Using Pipeline with Bower](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storages.html#using-pipeline-with-bower))

Answer (score 1):

I would leave your `bower_components` folder in your root, untouched and ignored by your VCS. Then use something like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to copy the selected files into a scripts folder somewhere and then use RequireJS to build those.

This allows you to easily update your bower components and prevents you needing to commit needless repository cruft into your repo.

You can use the Grunt concat or copy task to do this or try the [grunt-bowercopy](https://github.com/timmywil/grunt-bowercopy) task that will also run a `bower install` for you

Comment: I already do all this with bash scripts.  The same problem remains though.  After this is all done by bash or grunt, there are tons of unnecessary files left in the bower_components directory along with a few necessary files -- things like fonts and images.

Comment: If it's gitgnored does it make any difference? When you do a bower install they will all just come back. However if it really bothers you just delete the folder when your script has finished.

Comment: You have to install the bower_components in general as some of the dependencies look to those directories to get assets -- images and such.  What I'd like to do is delete everything except those needed assets.